# trying to change color of all text table fill colors in PPT?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PPT with 100s of slides and some text tables all over. Trying to change my color in those tables from green to blue.

[image: these]

to

[image]

Getting a compile error on this the line that has my RGB color #. any ideas?

```
        Sub TableAllBlack()

Dim lRaw As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape

With ActivePresentation
    For Each osld In .Slides
        For Each oShp In oSdl.Shapes
            Set oTbl = oShp.Table
                With oTbl
                    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241) 'Add your color here
                                End With
                            Next
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the double `.shape` in that row - it's not needed as you are having the `Shape` in the `With`-statement. BTW: you are dimming variables you don't use, you use variables that aren't dimmed ..

Comment: @Ike so I updated the code and am getting a compile error on                

 `Set oTbl = oShp.Table`

Comment: Not every shape has a table - you need to test if `oShp.HasTable` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.hastable

Answer (score 1):

As @Ike wrote in the comments, to get rid of the compiler error, you have to remove one "shape".

Either write

```
With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241)
```

Or

```
With .Cell(lRow, lCol)
    .Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241)
```

Or without using `With`:

```
.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241)
```

That said: You have more issues with your code. Firstly, quite some typos in your variable names - always use `Option Explicit` to catch such errors. For example:

```
Dim osld As Slide
For Each osld In .Slides
    For Each oShp In oSdl.Shapes
```

See? `osld` is different than `oSdl`. The latter is not defined. If you use `Option Explicit`, the compiler will complain and you see the error almost immediately. If not, `oSdl` is `Nothing` and you will get a runtime error 91           (Object variable or With block variable not set) which is much harder to understand.

And you write

```
For Each oShp In oSdl.Shapes
    Set oTbl = oShp.Table
```

This will fail when you have a shape on your slide that is not a table (because you cannot assign it to `oTbl`. You need to check the shape has a table using the property `HasTable`):

```
For Each oShp In oSdl.Shapes
    If oSdl.HasTable Then
        Set oTbl = oShp.Table
```

I also would advocate to use better variable names - `oShp`, `oSdl` and `oTbl` makes me dizzy reading the code. And don't use the wrongly understood hungarian notation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableAllBlack()
    Dim tableRow As Long, tableCol As Long
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim table As table
    
    With ActivePresentation
        For Each slide In .Slides
            For Each shape In slide.Shapes
                If shape.HasTable Then
                    Set table = shape.table
                    With table
                        For tableRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                            For tableCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                                .Cell(tableRow, tableCol).shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(211, 225, 241)
                            Next
                        Next
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ted Williams has it correct. Go through the shapes and if it's a table then change the color.

```
Sub TableAllRED()

Dim i, j, k As Integer

With ActivePresentation
    nslides = .Slides.Count
    For i = 1 To nslides
      j = .Slides(i).Shapes.Count
      For k = 1 To j
        .Slides(i).Shapes(k).Select
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.HasTable = msoTrue Then
            ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
      Next k
    Next i
    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You really don't want to select anything you don't absolutely have to. Doing so will slow the code down and will prevent it from working in some cases. @FunThomas has the correct answer here.

Comment: So, Steve Rindsberg, how would you solve the problem more efficiently?  One rule from MS was "Many properties and methods that apply to the Shape object and ShapeRange collection fail if applied to certain kinds of shapes. For example, the TextFrame property fails if applied to a shape that cannot contain text. If you are not positive that each shape in a ShapeRange collection can have a certain property or method applied to it, don't apply the property or method to the ShapeRange collection."  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/powerpoint/how-to/work-with-shapes-drawing-objects

Comment: Lug  See FunThomas' answer above. He doesn't .Select anything (which would make the code fail, among other times, in Slide Show mode, and in any case, makes for unnecessary blinking). And he tests to see if the shape .HasTable. Table cells by definition have text frames, so there's no issue there. If you're not working with tables, you can test each shape's .HasTextFrame property and if needed, then its TextFrame's .HasText property.